# Custom Notification from cloud messaging console not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firebase, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

1 - I am sending notification from firebase cloud messaging:

[image: google firebase console]

2 - After receiving the notification, I tried to customize in order to add action_click for the notification, using the following method:

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  const {title, body, image} = payload.notification;
  const {click_action} = payload.data;
  let notification= new Notification(title, {
    body, image
  });
  notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open(click_action, '_blank');
  };
});
```

3 - Chrome notification looks good, the action click is correct

[image]

4 - On firefox is not working, the notification does not show the image and the action click is wrong

[image: firefox notification]

Is there any other way to customize the firefox notification?